# Pressing "Proceed" on the Update Conflict Error results to Layout XML to not open when double clicked

Tags: android, android-studio

After pressing the proceed as advised to me, the XML layout on Res/layout folder to not open. Anybody Experiencing this? Thank you.

[image]

```
6:18:21 PM NoSuchMethodError: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;
6:18:29 PM NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/checks/SignatureOrSystemDetector: com/android/tools/lint/checks/SignatureOrSystemDetector
6:18:37 PM PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider
6:18:41 PM Gradle build finished with 2 warnings(s) in 4 sec
6:18:43 PM NoSuchMethodError: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;
6:18:45 PM NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/tools/lint/checks/SignatureOrSystemDetector: com/android/tools/lint/checks/SignatureOrSystemDetector
6:18:49 PM NoSuchMethodError: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;
6:18:53 PM NoSuchMethodError: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;: com.android.dvlib.DeviceSchema.getSchema()Ljavax/xml/validation/Schema;
```

Comment: After pressing proceed, I could not open the XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the update executable isn't running with admin privileges, so modifications aren't being allowed.  It's correctly indicating that you have no choice but to ignore them.

Comment: Is it safe to ignore them? So I guess, i will change the security of my android studio to full.

Comment: Ignoring them means your just not benefiting from anything add in those updates.  Your existing code will continue to work the same way.

Comment: I have a problem now. I could not Open the xml layout after upgrade with that error. I think this is not the answer.

Comment: Did you try running with admin privileges, or are you in an environment where you don't have control over that?

Comment: I have an admin privilege. Is there a way to revert back to the previous version?

Comment: I use the ADT, which uses SDKManager to handle updates, and that allows you to revert updates.  I'm not sure if Android Studio allows you to do the same thing our not.